# How to make mathematical chart with HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

[image: Target chart]

[image: HichCharts chart]

Hi there, I'm doing a web project which aims to replace a back-end chart renderer with front-end chart renderer. The front-end charting library I'm using is HighCharts. The 1st image shows what the chart supposed to look, and the 2nd is the chart rendered by HighCharts based on same data. As you can see, at point 3 & 4 (count from right to left), since their values are equal, the line between them are considered horizontal, which is different in image 1 as desired.

Is there anyway we can use HighCharts to achieve the first image - like chart? Cheers.

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when two points have the same value, then line will be rendered as straight one. You can change that by wrapping `getPointSpline`. Here is simple POC:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.spline.prototype, 'getPointSpline', function(p, points, point, i) {

    var path = p.call(this, points, point, i),
        offset = -10;

    if (points[i - 1] && points[i - 1].y === point.y) {
      path[2] += offset;
      path[4] += offset;
    }

    return path;
  });
})(Highcharts)
```

And working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99w72efv/8/

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts splice type series doesn't provide the kind of line approximation you are looking for. You could add more data points (that might be hidden) to get the shape that you are looking for.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/99w72efv/9/

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'spline'
    },
    yAxis: {max: 3},
    series: [{
      data: [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, {x: 11.5, y: 3.2, marker: {enabled:false}}, 3, 1, 2, {x: 14.5, y: 2.2, marker: {enabled:false}}, 2, 0, 1]
    }]
  });
});
```